# Is there any benefit of using Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) with Angular 4/5 application?

Tags: angular, angular5, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Can anyone help me to understand if there is any benefit of using **AMP** with **Angular 4/5**?

If it is beneficious, then how to integrate **AMP** with **Angular 4/5** so that in AoT build, the **AMP** components will be recognised?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that implementing AMP on an Angular app is close to impossible at this point in time. With some of the AMP standards and restrictions I know:

1. You cannot include external stylesheets, use inline CSS instead.
2. You are not allowed to have ANY custom JavaScript, use AMP components instead.
3. It errors on any custom attributes and custom tags.

I also couldn't find any progress or details regards of [Angular](https://angular.io/)+AMP so far.